# OSRMroadmanager constructor giving error

Tags: android, routes, osmdroid

I started working on openStreetMaps, using Osmdroid and OSMbonuspack libraries, i have problem with the OSRMroadmanager constructor, it is giving me error.

"Error:(52, 35) error: constructor OSRMRoadManager in class OSRMRoadManager cannot be applied to given types;

required: Context...
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

if there is a problem with arguments, which arguments should i pass to the constructor?

below is the code.
thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    //zoom controllers
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    //move to default view point
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(9);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

    //marker
    Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
    startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
    startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

    //refresh map
    map.invalidate();

    //string inside the marker box
    //startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.center));
    startMarker.setTitle("default position");

    //routing
    RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    waypoints.add(startPoint);
    GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9);
    waypoints.add(endPoint);

    Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

    Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);

    map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
    map.invalidate();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(this);
```

I apologize, following addition of the Context argument to the constructor, the tutorial had not been updated. Fixed now.

Comment: ok sir. thanks alot. And 1 more thing i want to know. can these libraries be used for offline mapping and routing, and is there any library or API which can be used for offline navigation?

Comment: Simplest way for offline routing is GraphHopper.

Comment: and for offline voice navigation?